# a displacement of time

Tags: history-of-philosophy, political-philosophy

1. What does "a displacement of time" mean in this context?
2. Does this "coincidence" imply a coincidence between the two world wars?

Context:

No one in the West was unaffected by the two world wars and the interesting **coincidence** may be that the advances in contemporary science that show a breaking of symmetries, **a displacement of time** and an upheaval of old laws and orders all happened against a backdrop of split and rupture on the world’s battlefields and a radical breakdown in any consistent moral and spiritual tradition.

(Art and Science by Sian Ede)

Comment: Welcome to Phil.SE; it's an interesting observation that I haven't seen remarked on before.

Answer (score 2):

The whole passage seems to me a rather superficial comparison between political events and revolutions in science.

ad 2. The coincidence is supposed to hold between the two world wars in the period 1914-1945 on one hand and the revolution in physics during the same time on the other hand.

ad 1. In my opinion, displacement of time is an unusual term in physics. Probably the author alludes to the change in the concept of time due to the Theory of Special Relativity. But note that the Special Theory of Relativity was published already in 1905.

Answer (score 0):

'Displacement in time' refers to 'upheaval in laws'; ie a rupture in the traditional order; the author is not talking about physical time as measured by clocks; consider instead the phrase 'our times', or 'nowadays' or even the opening line from Tolstoys *War and Peace*:

> it was the best of times and it was the worst of times

But, probably most appositely here: *zeitgeist* (the spirit (*geist*) of the time (*zeit*) - a notion taken from Hegel).

Consider too, the poem *Second Coming* by Yeats:

> The falcon cannot hear the falconer

Alluding to the break in authority and tradition; and hence

> The centre cannot hold; things fall apart

ie 'split and rupture'

> And what rough beast, it's hour come at last
>
> Slouches it's way to Bethleham

ie 'a radical breakdown in any consistent moral and spiritual tradition'.

This particular sentiment was prefigured by Arnold's *Dover Beach* (in 1867)!

> And we are here as on a darkling plain
>
> Swept with confused alarms of struggle and flight

The *coincidence* is not between the two World Wars, but between the breakdown in order in the Sciences, the Arts and Politics (in the broad sense).

No specific *causal* order is alluded to here or hinted at; still Dada, a North European art movement set itself against tradition through anger (which resurfaced in Punk); Futurism, centred in Italy, set itself against tradition (it denounced it) because technology wasn't nihilistic (a la Heidegger) but prophetic of a new order, and in many ways a dominant cultural moment today.

Dalis famous painting of *The persistence of memory* directly alludes Einsteins theory of time ie the curvature of spacetime; ie the curved timepiece; as does Picassos and Braques Cubism (the picture plane doesn't refer to a single time but many times).

note: It's worth pointing out that this narrative is far from the concerns of the author which is focuses on the contemporary linkage between Art and Science; which is outlined more by the playful poem by Edwin Morgan:

> ... anti-hero and anti-matter
>
> bubble chambers and EK Chambers
>
> genres and genera

Comment: Isn't this (also the OPs quote) just the history of postmodernism, retold for the umteenth time?

Comment: @Drux: I'm not suggesting that I'm offering any new insights here; but expanding on how to interpret the terms high-lighted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

### Coincidence

The coincidence is that the "advancements in contemporary science" that the author views as an "upheaval of old laws and orders" happened during a political "upheaval" of similar scale. The coincidence is both that science and the geo-political landscape where both drastically changed at the same time, and that this happened twice. I'm sure of course that the intention of the author is probably that this was no "coincidence" at all.

### Displacement of Time

I think this phrase is more artistic license than a reference to any specific scientific advancement. If we consider science progressing at some standard rate, then the periods marked by huge advancement increase this pace, and from one point of reference displace a lot of time. Basically, the time it would have taken under normal rates of innovation has been "displaced", causing a lot of science to be built in a shorter amount of time than would normally be expected.